# Positioning issues in D3 binary tree based icicle visualization of subnets

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I've created an interactive hierarchical D3 partition based visualization for displaying portions of a network. The visualization works by allowing users to traverse levels in the binary tree and down to a leaf level of /24 subnets.

A functioning example visualization can be interacted with on [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/rheone/7493ebb56b7ec51ebca9), with source and data available to create the visualization provided in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rheone/7493ebb56b7ec51ebca9) (not inlined due to size).

In general everything renders correctly, however after a transition the new position of some rect elements becomes corrupted. An example of which is seen in the following screen shot:

[image: bad display]

Thus far the corruption appears unpredictable, is apparently unrelated to the underlying data, and is fixed during the next transition. Sometimes clicking around triggers it, sometimes it doesn't.

What might be causing these visualization errors? At first I thought it to be a concurrency issue caused by an async call to multiple interactions at once, but debouncing doesn't seem to fix things. My next fear is that it is just too much data for D3 to handle, but that seems unlikely.

The issue occurs in both Chrome and Internet Explorer.